# how to split a 10 digit phone number into groups of digits?

Tags: c, split

I wanna convert a 10 digits phone number (ex: 1112223333) into 3 groups:

group 1 will be: 111

group 2: 222

and group 3: 3333

Then I want to join the groups to create a string like: (111)-222-3333

I searched a lot but found only how to split by 10 to get each digits or how to split using a delimiter which I don't have.

Can you show me please how to split a phone number into pieces?

EDIT:
I have smth like this:

```
void convert_phone(char *phone) {
    if (strlen(phone) != 10) return 0;
    int num;
    int i = strlen(phone) - 1;
    int array[strlen(phone)];
    while (num > 0) {
        array[i--] = num % 10;
        num /= 10;
        printf("%d\n", num);
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: After search, did you try to write an algo. or a program? we need that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int convert_phone(char *outbuff, const char *phone){
    if (strlen(phone) != 10) return 0;

    char gp1[3+1] = {0};
    char gp2[3+1] = {0};
    char gp3[4+1] = {0};
    strncpy(gp1, phone, 3);
    strncpy(gp2, phone + 3, 3);
    strncpy(gp3, phone + 6, 4);
    sprintf(outbuff, "(%s)-%s-%s", gp1, gp2, gp3);

    return 1;
}
int main(void){
    const char *phone_num = "1112223333";
    char buff[sizeof("(XXX)-XXX-XXXX")];
    if(convert_phone(buff, phone_num))
        printf("%s\n", buff);//(111)-222-3333
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @ShaMora Just a small reminder, using `sprintf` can be unsafe if you're not 100% sure the buffer is large enough. Consider using [`snprintf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you have 10 digits input number as string, and you want groups in strings then you can use `sscanf` function:

```
sscanf(str, "%3s%3s%4s", grp1, grp2, grp3);
```

And finally combine into a desired string using `sprintf`:

```
sprintf(result, "(%s)-%s-%s", grp1, grp2, grp3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a string, add the opening parentheses, add the three first digits to the string, add the closing parentheses, add a dash to the string, get the next three digits and add them to the string, add the second dash, and finally add the last four digits to the string.

Comment: I like your solution but I don't know how to get first 3 digits, then the next 3 and the last 4

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char *number = "9703654329";
    char *k = number;
    int i=0,c=0,s=0,b=0,a=0;
    printf("(");
    for(i=strlen(number);i;i--)
    {
        printf("%c",*k);
        k = (char *)k + sizeof(char);
        c++;
        if(c==3 && s!=2)
        {
            a+=1;
            if(a==1)
            {
                printf(")");
            }
            printf("-");
            c=0;
            s+=1;
        }
    }
}
```